# Loading model causes different result (probably dropout active)

Tags: python, pytorch

In Pytorch when i run a model after training (without loading) i get good results. But when i load the model i get completely different results that are false. I have a dropout in my forward. I can not figure out how to do this because there hasnt been a single post about it in a year and things have changed in pytorch. Here is the code (it has a few features implemented):

```
    class Netz(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Netz, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 2, kernel_size=5) #(wir haben 3 input chanel, output chanel setzen wir auf 10) da wir mit Bilder arbeiten kommt eine convolutional Schicht rein, gleich als erstes
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(2, 4, kernel_size=5) #normalerweise macht man gleich mehrere convolutional Schichten
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(4, 8, kernel_size=5) #mit den Zahlen kann man am Ende noch ein bisschen herumspielen
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(7616, 1000)
        #fully connected layer soll als input genau die Anzahl an Neuronen haben, die torch.Size(, ., ., .) => . mal . mal .  ausspuckt
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1000, 2)
        
    def forward(self, x): #gehen davon aus, dass irgendetwas kaputt gehen wird
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x,2)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x,2)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x,2)          
        x = x.view(-1, 7616) #-1, da der erste Wert, also die batch size, uns nicht interessiert
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x)) # als Aktivierungslayer für unser erstes fully connected layer
        x = F.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.softmax(x, dim=1)
        #jetzt müssen wir in unseren fully connected layer umsteigen, aber wir wissen ja nicht, wie unsere Daten in dem Fall jetzt aussehen
        exit()

model = Netz()
optimizer = optim.RMSprop(model.parameters(), lr = 0.001) #Learning rate

def train(epoch): #model existiert zwar noch nicht, aber wir erschaffen uns unser eigenes model
    model.train() #model auf train setzen, damit es auch wirklich trainiert wird und nicht nur ausgeführt
    for idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_data): # Daten aus vorgefertigten Daten beziehen, wir brauchen hier die train data
        target = torch.Tensor(target)
        data = Variable(data)
        target = Variable(target) # müssen data und target ja immer noch als Variablen verarbeiten
        optimizer.zero_grad() #setzen unseren Gradienten auf 0, damit wir überhaupt etwas lernen können
        out = model(data) #output soll das model data sein
        criterion = F.binary_cross_entropy #wollen ja Bilder klassifizieren in zwei Klassen
        loss = criterion(out, target) #wollen unser Loss als criterion von output und target berechnen -- zu beachten: target hat zwei Elemente und am Ende soll unser output auch zwei Elemente haben
        loss.backward() # wollen unseren Loss back - propagaten
        optimizer.step() # wollen unseren Optimizer sagen, dass er etwas tun soll
# das war es mit unserem Trainingsalgorithmus 

epoch_num = range(0,int(args.epochs))

if path.exists(args.model) == False: #wir schauen ob unsere Model schon trainiert ist
    for idx, epoch in enumerate(epoch_num, start=1): #wollen 30 epcohen lang trainieren
        print("Epoch " + str(idx) + " out of " + str(max(epoch_num)+1) + " started!")
        train(epoch)    
        print("Epoch " + str(idx) + " out of " + str(max(epoch_num)+1) + " finished!")
    torch.save(model, args.model) #wir speichern unsere trainierte Model
else:
    model = torch.load(args.model)
```

Comment: Make sure to evaluate inside `with torch.no_grad():`  and also use `model.eval()` before doing any forward pass for evaluation. `model.eval()` should take care of dropout and batch norm layers.

Comment: Hello. It didnt help. It still gives a different result before and after, and my results appear less accurate with torch.no_grad().